# Isometry between Minkosky space and Tangent space

Tags: differential-geometry, isometry

In this notes  [Geometric Wave Equations](https://arxiv.org/abs/1208.4706) by Stefan Waldmann at   page 70  they have

> Having a fixed Lorentz metric $g$ on a spacetime manifold $M$ we can
> now transfer the notions of special relativity, see e.g. 50 , to $(M,
>  g)$. In fact, each tangent space $\left(T_{p} M, g_{p}\right)$ is
> isometrically isomorphic to Minkowski spacetime $\left(\mathbb{R}^{n},
> \eta\right)$ with $\eta=\operatorname{diag}(+1,-1, \ldots,-1)$, by
> choosing a Lorentz frame: there exist tangent vectors $e_{i} \in T_{p}
>  M$ with $i=1, \ldots, n$ such that $$ g_{p}\left(e_{i},
>  e_{j}\right)=\eta_{i j}=\pm \delta_{i j} . $$

We say that two manifolds $M$ and $N$ are isometric if we have vectors $v \in T_pM$  ,$u \in T_{\phi(p)}N$ and a map $\phi:M\rightarrow N$ such that

$g(v,v)=g'(\phi^*v,\phi^*v)$ where $g$ is a metric in $M$ ,  $g'$ is a metric in $N$ and $\phi^*$ denotes a pushfoward.

Now the definiton if isometry is  refers  to two manifolds,but in the notes they are claiming an isometry bettween a manifold and a tangent space.

How this isometry is constructed?

Comment: First, pushforward should be written $\phi_*$. Second, they're claiming an isometry between the tangent space $T_pM$ and Minkowski $\Bbb R^n$, i.e., an isometry between two vector spaces. The isometry, as they said, is given by choosing a Lorentz frame $e_i$ and sending it to the standard basis for Minkowski $\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin at page 64 he defined Minkowski spacetime as a manifold

Comment: Every vector space is a manifold, yes.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin He is considering $R^N$ as manifold not as a vector space. You can consider $R^N$ as manifold without considering it as a vector space

Comment: You're being too stubborn. The isometry is given by the vector space isomorphism they and I described.